# Where to share RPG adventures?

Tags: campaign-development

Is there a good place to share some RPG modules that I've made? There's no IP information. Combat information is generic and things like magic item treasure are randomly generated. It's based in my world, but the modules are made so they could really be played in any world. There are things like maps, NPC information, and story contained in the modules.

Comment: What do you mean with IP? IP address? Intellectual Property (of the game)?

Comment: Hi Mu, and welcome to the site. This question's likely to get closed, as recommendation-requests have a long history of being hard to make work in the Stack format. We do curate [a list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970) which may be useful to you, one of which is our very own [chat]. Good luck!

Comment: IP as in intellectual property. There's no references like Zombie (pgXXX Monster Manual 5e)